# Numpy, how to convert a 2D array to 3D (by grouping cols to 2 list)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

E.g.

Before converting

```
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

After converting

```
array([[[0, 0], [0]],
       [[0, 1], [1]],
       [[1, 0], [1]],
       [[1, 1], [0]]])
```

I did it by looping the rows and slicing each row (e.g. [0, 0, 0]) into 2 lists (e.g. [[0, 0], [0]]). Any numpy-style shortcut?

Comment: Note your second array is no longer `dtype=np.int` since you have uneven column sizes, it becomes `dtype=object`, is that what you want?

Comment: @jamylak yes, you're right, the dtype of the second is object, it works without error in my program, but I was also puzzled by its dtype. The structure is basically what I want though

Comment: Do you actually need it to be an object like that or are alternative solutions possible? For example, take a look at slicing (assuming `x` is your array): `x[:,0:2], x[:,2]`

Comment: Thank you @WoLpH , I actually don't need it to be an object. I just intended to processed it like that for later usage, now I think I should keep it as an 2d array, and just slicing it while using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do fancy numpy indexing I suppose:

```
>>> a=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
>>> b=np.array([a[:,0:2].tolist(),a[:,2:3].tolist()])
>>> b
array([[[0, 1], [3, 4], [6, 7], [9, 10]],
       [[2], [5], [8], [11]]], dtype=object)
>>> b[0][0][0],b[0][0][1],b[1][0][0]
(0, 1, 2)
```

The addition of `.tolist()` will make a copy of `a`.

Or, if you want the object inside `b` to remain a reference or view to `a`:

```
>>> b=np.array([a[:,0:2],a[:,2:3]])
>>> b
array([[[0 1], [3 4], [6 7], [ 9 10]],
       [[2], [5], [8], [11]]], dtype=object)
>>> b[0][0][0],b[0][0][1],b[1][0][0]
(0, 1, 2)
```

Then `b` will change when `a` does:

```
>>> a[0][0]=23
>>> a
array([[23,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
>>> b
array([[[23  1], [3 4], [6 7], [ 9 10]],
       [[2], [5], [8], [11]]], dtype=object)
>>> b[0][0].flags['OWNDATA']
False
```